# How can I avoid colored light reflections?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

so I'm sorta new to Blender and stumbled upon a problem which is probably easy to fix. So I realized that the color of the ground gets reflected onto other surfaces during the render, as seen on this picture:

[image]

How can I prevent the green color from appearing on other things than the ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by decreasing the number of bounces in *Render settings > Light paths*:

[image]

However, note that [this is a phenomenon in the real world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflector_%28photography%29), and disabling it may make your renders look more fake or unrealistic.

Comment: gandalf3: I think that you'd know more about this than me so perhaps you could elaborate on this idea that I saw somewhere recently in some video that may have been Godfried(BlenderDiplome)???  Anyways, I vaguely remember the setup uses two shaders and a Light path node to control the mix so that when the rays are camera rays then one shader is used and when the rays are indirect then the other shader is used.  Maybe this is only good for Glossy but perhaps you might concoct something that helps with a diffuse setup as well since you do seem to have skill with these types of setups.Cheers.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I'm not quite sure what you mean.. You can mix shaders based on ray type so one shader appears to the camera, and a different shader appears to the objects. But I'm not sure what you want to do with this?