# Why is my texture projecting onto other objects?

Tags: texturing

Alright, so let me start off with I'm fairly new to blender, so this may just be an error on my part for not using a certain setting or something.

My problem is that my texture is semi-appearing on the walls of a box I'm making.
At 500 samples:
[image]

In the 500 sample one it's not as major of an issue, but at lower samples it is. Whenever I changed the textured floor to just a plain pink diffuse bsdf, the problem still occurs.
[image]

In the first picture I used an image texture plugged into a velvet and glossy shader which is plugged into a mixed shader. In the second picture just a pink diffuse bsdf is used.

Edit: I should've asked how to stop this from happening, not why.

Comment: This is like in real life : if you put light on a red surface which is near a white wall, you will see some red on the wall. Is your question only about "why" or do you want to avoid this behavior in Blender ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: this can be a solution : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/how-can-i-avoid-colored-light-reflections. Please confirm us if it is really in your context.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you so much. That'll also help in the future with future projects, so thank you very much for that too.

Comment: You are welcome. I will vote to indicate your question as duplicate of the one from the link I gave you (that's the process to avoid too many answers here).